# targeting using conditions or loops

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

[image]So I have 6 product cards (2 rows 3 columns) displaying different products with image, name, price, review stars etc.. Each of these product cards have been given an id of product1, product2 etc. And on top of all these cards are 3 icons which show up on mouse hover. The icons are view icon, cart icon and Wishlist icon. Now my question is, on the click of the add to cart icon of a "particular" card I want to add "that" card's product id to local storage. For eg : if I hover on and click the 4th card's add to cart icon, that card's product id which is product 4 should be saved in the local storage. How do I do this? Which loop or conditional to use and how? Pls help!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card mb-4" id="product1">
    <div class="icons d-flex justify-content-center" id="card_icons">
      <a href="#"><img class='img1' src="Images/heart-icon-trans.png" alt="inner heart icon"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="Images/eye-icon-trans.png" alt="inner eye icon"></a>
      <a id="cart-icon1"><img src="Images/shopping-icon-trans.png" alt="inner shopping icon"></a>
    </div>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/product1.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <span class='new_tag'>NEW</span>
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Dummy Text Lorel</h5>
      <p class="card-text mb-0"><strong>Rs 1099.0</strong> <del>Rs 2748.0</del><span class="offer">(60%Off)</span></p>
      <div class="stars-group d-flex align-items-center mt-2" id="starsgroup">
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star-empty.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star-empty.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No loop is required.  This sort of logic involves contextual lookups, originating from the element interacted with.  To provide more information, we will need to see an example of a card's markup.

Comment: An alternative to the contextual lookups would also be to provide the product id on each of the icons that relate to them.  If that path were taken, you wouldn't have to find the associated data.  It would have it.  There are various ways you can take this.

Comment: So your id is on the parent `div.card`.  So what you can do is, for the event listeners on the buttons, you can get the `closest('.card')` which should find the parent card div, and then just grab it's `.id` to get the `product1` or whatever value it has.

Comment: @Taplar I've added the snippet above for your reference.. What's the most efficient and simple way to do this? I have many cards like these and thought will have to loops through each of those.. my logic was as follows : foreach of the card, on click of the cart icon button of that card, save that card's id to local storage. How do I convert this to working code?

Comment: @Taplar tried the closest() but not working..I keep getting error that cannot set property onclick of null..
`let card = document.querySelector(".card") 
 let cart_icon = document.getElementById("cart-icon");

cart_icon.onclick = function() {
  console.log(closest(card).id);
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a really quick example of how you could do this with closest.  Take note that on each of the links I added a class, to help identify which elements this logic should relate to.  Since I assume different behavior should happen for each link, I made them distinct classes.

So now lets look at the logic.  The logic creates a click event listener on the body.  We do this since click events bubble up the DOM.  This allows us to have one event handler that handles this logic for all the relevant elements on the page.

The logic checks to see if the element that was clicked, belongs to an element with one of our classes.  So either the link or the image in the link was clicked.  If it was, we can grab the id from the parent card and do what we want with it.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.closest('.inner-eye, .inner-heart, .shopping')) {
    console.log(e.target.closest('.card').id);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card mb-4" id="product1">
    <div class="icons d-flex justify-content-center" id="card_icons">
      <a href="#" class="inner-heart"><img class='img1' src="Images/heart-icon-trans.png" alt="inner heart icon"></a>
      <a href="#" class="inner-eye"><img src="Images/eye-icon-trans.png" alt="inner eye icon"></a>
      <a id="cart-icon1" class="shopping"><img src="Images/shopping-icon-trans.png" alt="inner shopping icon"></a>
    </div>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/product1.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <span class='new_tag'>NEW</span>
    <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <h5 class="card-title">Dummy Text Lorel</h5>
      <p class="card-text mb-0"><strong>Rs 1099.0</strong> <del>Rs 2748.0</del><span class="offer">(60%Off)</span></p>
      <div class="stars-group d-flex align-items-center mt-2" id="starsgroup">
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star-empty.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
        <img class="stars" src="Images/star-empty.png" alt="star-rating" role="icon" aria-label='star rating'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: how do I save these individual id's to local storage without overwriting them every time I click another icon..? what's happening now is when I click the first card cart icon it gets saved to local storage but the moment I click the next next icon, that card's id overwrites the first one.. I don't want this.. I want all id's with unique keys whichever clicked on to be saved so I can use it in my cart page.. how do I do this?
`document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.closest('.shopping')) {
    localStorage.setItem("Product", e.target.closest('.card').id);
  }
});`

Comment: You'll have to store the values in an array, in storage.  You'll add/remove them from the array.